# ExecuteExcel4Macro - Run-time error 1004 "The formula you typed contains an error."

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

> Run-time error 1004 "The formula you typed contains an error."

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim wbPath, wbName, wsName, cellRef, Ret As String
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    wbPath = "N:\BVN\1W\02 GpDS\04 Sp\03 Horeca\04 SBC\02 Private\01 Boekhouding sbc\"
    wbName = "TEGOEDEN-AVOIR.xls"
    wsName = "CIS-A4"
    cellRef = "F6"
    Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True)
    Ret = CStr(Ret)
    Me.Label11.Caption = xlApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
End Sub
```

I added a watch on the variable and it seems ok :

```
"'N:\BVN\1W\02 GpDS\04 Sp\03 Horeca\04 SBC\02 Private\01 Boekhouding sbc\[TEGOEDEN-AVOIR.xls]CIS-A4'!$F$6"
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong is that you need to use an R1C1 reference:

```
Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).address(True, True, xlR1C1)
```

will work (as long as the rest of it is correct of course!)

Answer (score -1):

<s>The path belongs to the workbook filename, not separately in front of it:</s>

Another hint (not causing an error, yet): this

```
Dim wbPath, wbName, wsName, cellRef, Ret As String
```

will define 4 `Variants` and one `string`. What you really intend is

```
Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String, Ret As String
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not true. The path belongs where it is in the original code.